# PHP includes overlap eacher other

Tags: php, include, overlap

So I just learned about the include function, I made a:
include ("header.php"); and 
include ("mainSection.php"); but they seem to overlap each other.
is it something with my css or html?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Chocoot</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <?php
           include ("header.php");
           include ("mainSection.php");
         ?>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The header.php

```
<header id="logoheader">
    <h1 id="logo">Chocoot</h1>
    <div id="orangeborder1">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href ="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href ="chocolate.php">Chocolate</a></li>
                <li><a href ="beans.php">Beans</a></li>
                <li><a href ="history.php">History</a></li>
                <li><a href ="contact.php">Contact</a></li>     
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
        <div id="slider"></div>
        <div id="orangeborder2"></div>
</header>
```

The mainSection.php

```
    <section id="midSection">

    </section>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#logoheader{
    width: 1366px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #2b292a;
}

body{
    background-color: #171515;
}

#wrapper{
    width: 1366px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    background-color:#2b292a;

}
header{
    width: 1366px;
    height: 475px;
    float: left;
}
#logo{
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 28px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    float: left;
}
#orangeborder1{
    width: 1366px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #2b292a;
}

#orangeborder1{
    width: 1366px;
    height: 86px;
    background-color: #9b3210;
    float: left;    
}
nav ul li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 28px;
}

nav ul li a{    
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul li:first-child{
    margin-left: 250px;
}
nav ul li:nth-child(2){
    margin-left: 64px;
}
nav ul li:nth-child(3){
    margin-left: 90px;
}
nav ul li:nth-child(4){
    margin-left: 63px;
}
nav ul li:nth-child(5){
    margin-left: 50px;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#slider{
    width: 1366px;
    height: 301px;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
#slider2{
    width: 1366px;
    height: 301px;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

#orangeborder2{
    width: 1366px;
    height: 59px;
    background-color: #9B3210;
    float: left;
}
#midSection{
    width: 1366px;
    height: 570px;
    background-color: #2b292a;
    float: left;
}
#pictureContainer{
    width: 250px;
    height: 570px;
    float: left;

}
footer{
    width: 1366px;
    height: 155px;
    background-color: #433f40;
    float: left;
}
```

I hope you can help me :s

Comment: yes , it is "something with my css or html"

Comment: Check the size of your items in your CSS. The header is 475 pixels tall. The midsection is not told to start at 475 pixels down from the top.

Comment: The fact that the code is in "include" files means nothing to how it is rendered.  The browser couldn't care less.  So, yes, your problem is somewhere in your rendered code.  I suggest Firefox or Chrome Inspect Element, to find the problem.

Comment: Well, unless you provide the actual non-working code, I suggest a simple question deletion since it can't really receive an answer in its current state. Oh and don't thank us or ask for help in the question (comments are okay =p), that's why we're all here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the 'height: 30px;' in the #logoheader block of your css. So it looks like this:

```
#logoheader {
width: 1366px;
background-color: #2b292a;
}
```

Does that do anything? You should not have to tell elements how far to start down on a page. By default they will stack on each other unless otherwise told.